# Error opening trace file: No such file or directory(2) (1) no such table: ContactListTable Tried for hours can't find solution

Tags: java, android, android-listview, runtime-error, forceclose

I am new to android and java. I tried to check my code against an example but somehow the application keeps forced close while the example works perfectly well. I need help please! Thanks in advance!

*New Logcat*

```
07-31 16:51:02.145: E/Trace(16532): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-31 16:51:02.175: D/AndroidRuntime(16532): Shutting down VM
07-31 16:51:02.180: W/dalvikvm(16532): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fdb2a0)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.Elson.ProjectVersion.ContactsActivityApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4254)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1324)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:536)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:821)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:376)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at com.Elson.ProjectVersion.Contacts.toString(Contacts.java:91)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at com.Elson.ProjectVersion.ContactsActivityApplication.readContactsFromDB(ContactsActivityApplication.java:57)  
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at com.Elson.ProjectVersion.ContactsActivityApplication.onCreate(ContactsActivityApplication.java:26)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4251)
07-31 16:51:02.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16532):    ... 10 more
```

Contacts.java

```
 package com.Elson.ProjectVersion;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class Contacts implements Comparable<Contacts> {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int Phone;
    private int Email;
    private Date date;
    private double runningAverage;




    public Contacts(String name, int Phone,  Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.Phone = Phone;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Contacts(long id, String name,int Phone) {
        this.id=id;
        this.Phone=Phone;
        this.name= (name);

    }


    public long getId() {

        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(int Phone) {
        this.Phone = Phone;
    }
    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public long getDateEpoch(){
        return date.getTime()/1000;
    }
    public void setDateEpoch(long seconds){
        date= new Date (seconds*1000);
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }




    public void setRunningAverage(double runningAverage) {
        this.runningAverage = runningAverage;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object that){
        Contacts bs = (Contacts) that;

        return this.date.equals(bs.date);
      }


    @Override



    public String toString() {
        String result;

        // "ID" + id +" "
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        result = df.format(date) + "" + name + "" + Phone ; 



        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contacts another) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
```

}

ContactsActivityApplication

```
package com.Elson.ProjectVersion;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

import static com.Elson.ProjectVersion.MyContactSQL.*;

public class EnterContactsActivity extends Activity {

private Button saveButton;
private EditText NameEditText;
private EditText PhoneEditText;
private Button ExitButton;
private EditText EmailEditText;
private TextView date;

private int month;//private within class
private int day;
private int year;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addcontacts);

    setUpViews();

    Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    Date today = calendar.getTime();
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    String cs = df.format(today);
    date.setText(cs);
}


public void saveClickHandler(View v){

    String ContactsScore;
    ContactsScore= NameEditText.getText().toString();
    String name = String.format(ContactsScore, null);
    ContactsScore= PhoneEditText.getText().toString();
    int Phone = Integer.parseInt(ContactsScore);

    Log.d("EnterContacts" , "I hear the Save Button");

    if( isValid(Phone) ) {
        Contacts contacts;
        Date dateofGames= new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day).getTime();
        contacts = new Contacts (name , Phone ,  dateofGames);

        ContactsActivityApplication app  = (ContactsActivityApplication) getApplication();
        //might be wrong

        Log.d("DeBUGGING", "app is this type: " + app.getClass().getName());
        //need add the function addBowlingScores
        app.addallContacts(contacts);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Contact has been Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

    else{
        //pop up a dialog that data is invalid
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Invalid Phone Number")
               .setMessage("Phone numbers cannot have more than 8 numbers")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", 

                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel(); 
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    }



private boolean isValid(int Phone ) {

    if(Phone > 0 && Phone <100000000)
        return true;
    return false;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


public void handleShowHistoryClick (View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HistoryActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


private void setUpViews()
{
    ExitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnExit);
    saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnSave);
    NameEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameEditText);
    PhoneEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhoneEditText);
    EmailEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailEditText);
    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DateTextView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addcontacts, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

EnterContactsActivity

```
package com.Elson.ProjectVersion;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EnterContactsActivity extends Activity {

private Button saveButton;
private EditText NameEditText;
private EditText PhoneEditText;
private Button ExitButton;
private EditText EmailEditText;
private TextView date;

private int month;//private within class
private int day;
private int year;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addcontacts);

    setUpViews();

    Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    Date today = calendar.getTime();
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    String cs = df.format(today);
    date.setText(cs);
}


public void saveClickHandler(View v){

    String ContactsScore;
    ContactsScore= NameEditText.getText().toString();
    int name = Integer.parseInt(ContactsScore);
    ContactsScore= PhoneEditText.getText().toString();
    int Phone = Integer.parseInt(ContactsScore);
    ContactsScore = EmailEditText.getText().toString();
    int Email = Integer.parseInt(ContactsScore);

    Log.d("EnterContacts" , "I hear the Save Button");

    if( isValid(name) && isValid(Phone) && isValid(Email) ) {
        Contacts contacts;
        Date dateofGames= new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day).getTime();
        contacts = new Contacts (name , Phone , Email, dateofGames);

        ContactsActivityApplication app  = (ContactsActivityApplication) getApplication();
        //might be wrong

        Log.d("DeBUGGING", "app is this type: " + app.getClass().getName());
        //need add the function addBowlingScores
        app.addallContacts(contacts);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Contact has been Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

    else{
        //pop up a dialog that data is invalid
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Invalid Phone Number")
               .setMessage("Phone numbers cannot have more than 8 numbers")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", 

                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel(); 
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    }
private boolean isValid(int phone) {

    if(phone <= 0 && phone >=100000000)
        return true;
    return false;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


private void setUpViews()
{
    ExitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnExit);
    saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnSave);
    NameEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameEditText);
    PhoneEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhoneEditText);
    EmailEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailEditText);
    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DateTextView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addcontacts, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

MyContactsSQL

```
package com.Elson.ProjectVersion;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.util.Log;
```

public class MyContactSQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DB_NAME ="MyContactSQL.SQLite";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static String CONTACT_LIST_TABLE = "ContactListTable";
public static String RECORD_ID ="ID";
public  static String NAME = "NAME";
public static String PHONE_NUMBER="PhoneNumber";

public MyContactSQL(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase contactListDB) {


    String sqlStatement = "create table " + CONTACT_LIST_TABLE 
            + " ("
            + RECORD_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
            + NAME + " long,"
            + PHONE_NUMBER +" integer"
            +");";


           Log.d("Contact Database", sqlStatement);

           contactListDB.execSQL(sqlStatement);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

}
```

}

HistoryActivity

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HistoryActivity extends ListActivity {

Bundle savedInstanceState;
private ArrayList <Contacts> allContacts;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    setContentView(R.layout.history_layout);

    //get data from the App
    ContactsActivityApplication app = (ContactsActivityApplication) getApplication();
    allContacts = app.getAllContacts();


    //View  --- Adapter  ------ Data 

    setListAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<Contacts> (this, R.layout.history_row,
                    allContacts
                    ));

        ListView listView = this.getListView();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(
                 new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        verifyDeleteRow(position);
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "I hear item selected:" + position);
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                 }

                 );
}

private void verifyDeleteRow(final int position){
    //pop up a dialog to confirm delete row
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Delete this Series?")
           .setMessage("Do you want to delete this data?" + allContacts.get(position))
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setNegativeButton("NO! Leave it there!", 

                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel(); 
                }
            })
           .setPositiveButton("Delete", 

            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Contacts toDelete = allContacts.get(position);

                    ContactsActivityApplication app = (ContactsActivityApplication) getApplication();
                    app.deleteBowlingScores(toDelete);
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
}
```

Comment: Error shows that there is no Table in Database named ContactListTable.

Comment: I know. But how am i suppose to solve this? I did create in my code.

Comment: Have You checked that there is created table in Database??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQLHelper class you have Created Database with "DB_Name" in quotes. that means your dbname would be DB_Name.

```
super(context, "DB_NAME", null, DB_VERSION);
```

do like this

```
super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: now i got this error >> E/SQLiteLog(20989): (1) near "tableContactListTable": syntax error

Comment: "create table" then needs space. like this "create table "+TableName

Comment: E/Trace(23021): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 D/Contact Database(23021): create table ContactListTable (ID interger primary key autoincrement not null,NAME integer,PhoneNumber integer);                                                     E/SQLiteLog(23021): (1) AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY                                                              Does this mean my DB file is not created? cause my phone is rooted and can't access file explorer. I using some application to open the DB file.

Comment: you have wrote wrong spelling of integer. and ofcourse if there is an error then your table is not created.

Comment: 07-31 15:12:18.685: W/dalvikvm(6948): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fdb2a0)
07-31 15:12:18.720: E/AndroidRuntime(6948): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 15:12:18.720: E/AndroidRuntime(6948): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
When i clicked the saved button i got this -.-! The application is running though. Thank you for being so patient.

Comment: I need full stacktrace.

Comment: ContactsActivityApplication app  = new ContactsActivityApplication();

Comment: The log is at the bottom of the post!

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "elson" means that your Phone and Email variable should be String and not Integer.

Comment: I tried using string. But then another problem came up. I will re-edit the post

Comment: You have got nullpointer Exception in Date. so check is your date getting correctly in read contacts ??

Comment: I should put it as null?

Comment: depends on you. if you want to save date then you need to enter date. otherwise its ok..

Comment: okk good.. then you can select answer as accepted and upvote it.